# LNK1169 error when overriding inherited functions

Tags: c++, linker

So I'm using the olcConsoleGameEngine (source here as its too large to copy paste https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/videos/blob/master/olcConsoleGameEngine.h) and I'm using a class that inherits from it as the basis for the game, this is the header file:

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "olcConsoleGameEngine.h"

class Game : public olcConsoleGameEngine
{
public:
    Game();

protected:
    /*
    virtual bool OnUserCreate()
    {
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime)
    {
        Fill(0, 0, ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), PIXEL_SOLID, FG_BLUE);
        return true;
    }
    */
    virtual bool OnUserCreate();
    virtual bool OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime);
};

#endif
```

Notice the comments, declaring and defining this way is the only I have got it to compile so far (making sure to remove declaration in the cpp aswell)

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{
}

bool Game::OnUserCreate()
{
    return true;
}

bool Game::OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime)
{
    return true;
}
```

And in main I just have the standard code for setting up the window, which I know works since declaring the Update and Create functions in the .h works with no errors and gives correct output. It seems that as soon as I include Game.h in Game.cpp I get the linker error, which is:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl GetFontCoords(int,int *,int *)" (?GetFontCoords@@YAXHPAH0@Z) already defined in Game.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl font_decode_custom_base64(void)" (?font_decode_custom_base64@@YAXXZ) already defined in Game.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "protected: static struct std::atomic<bool> olcConsoleGameEngine::m_bAtomActive" (?m_bAtomActive@olcConsoleGameEngine@@1U?$atomic@_N@std@@A) already defined in Game.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "int (__stdcall* wglSwapInterval)(int)" (?wglSwapInterval@@3P6GHH@ZA) already defined in Game.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "unsigned char * pxplus_ibm_cga" (?pxplus_ibm_cga@@3PAEA) already defined in Game.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "char * pxplus_ibm_cga_enc" (?pxplus_ibm_cga_enc@@3PADA) already defined in Game.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "protected: static class std::condition_variable olcConsoleGameEngine::m_cvGameFinished" (?m_cvGameFinished@olcConsoleGameEngine@@1Vcondition_variable@std@@A) already defined in Game.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "protected: static class std::mutex olcConsoleGameEngine::m_muxGame" (?m_muxGame@olcConsoleGameEngine@@1Vmutex@std@@A) already defined in Game.obj
1>C:\Dev\C++Projects\WarAutomata\Debug\WarAutomata.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

int main() {
    Game game;
    game.ConstructConsole(640, 480, 1, 1);
    game.Start();
    return 0;
}
```

So in the program's current state I'd have the declare every function in the header, which is obviously not ideal. Any help with this problem would be really appreciated.

Comment: The code you have shown has nothing to do with the linker errors you have shown. Something else is going on. The linker is complaining that duplicate symbols are being defined by both `Main.cpp` and `Game.cpp`, which would imply that a common header (like `olcConsoleGameEngine.h`, or something it `#include`s) is not declaring those symbols correctly.

Comment: Putting `std::atomic<bool> olcConsoleGameEngine::m_bAtomActive(false);` in a header is blatantly stupid. The writer of this library may have a reason for why they did this in the documentation, but it's going to be very hard to make it a good one.

Comment: That header is not made for being included in more than one translation unit. You need to put everything that depends on it in a single file.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @RemyLebeau I'm aware of this, theyre found within the source in the github link, however if I just declare the functions as shown in the commented section the program will compile fine, so I dont believe the individual linker errors are that helpful

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok, so basically what you're saying is that I would have to declare every function in the header, and including the .h anywhere else would just break it and I wouldn't be able to fix that?

Comment: @JamesMclaughlin I think what molbdnilo is saying is don't use `#inlcude "olcConsoleGameEngine.h"` where it may end up being used by multiple `.cpp` files in your project. Create a separate `.cpp` just for including `olcConsoleGameEngine.h`. If you need to use the engine's functionality in multiple `.cpp` files in your project, you will have to use the functionality only inside that one `.cpp` file, and then create your own wrappers to access it privately without exposing it to your own `.cpp` files.

Comment: @user4581301 you're probably right, but the writer is genuinely a really good teacher. He has a really informative channel on YouTube that showcases a lot of really interesting things he makes in this engine as well as a few others he's designed. You should have a look, there's a link in his GitHub I believe.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Ok thank you, this seems like the right solution. I might end up just using the OOP version of the engine though, and hopefully avoid the extra hassle that using this version seems to create. Thanks alot for the help anyway.

Comment: @JamesMclaughlin seems the author made a mistake of declaring several `static` variables at the bottom of the `olcConsoleGameEngine.h` file, which means every `.cpp` file that includes that `.h` file will get its own copy of the variables, causing linker errors. They should instead be *declared* as `extern` in the `.h` file, and then *defined* in one of the library's own `.cpp` files.

Comment: Could be a great teacher, and this could be an attempt at simplifying things for educational purposes much like Stroustrup's std_lib_facilities header which gets people off the ground quickly, but then becomes a bit of a boat anchor. You can probably strategically split stuff out of olcConsoleGameEngine.h, those static variables for example, and move them into a cpp file or different header that you include once and only once and keep on rolling. Aaaand while I was typing this that's pretty much what Remy suggested. Teach me to go to the bathroom.